# Issues with if statements within Lambdas Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7

I am currently writing some code to scale vector graphics, but I am having some issues writing the error handling code in Python, particularly in the line that sets scaled_points within scalePoints. The function takes a list of coordinates (as tuples), a viewport size, and a shrink factor, and returns a scaled set of coordinates.

I am trying to avoid division by zero by using if statements within the lambda, but under certain test cases it does not appear to work. For instance, `scalePoints([(0.0,1.0)], 300, 10)` causes division by zero to occur, but `scalePoints([(0.0,0.0)], 300, 10)` does not, and I'm not quite sure why this is.

```
def scalePoints(points, viewport_size, shrink_factor):
    min_x = findMinX(points)
    max_x = findMaxX(points)

    width = max_x - min_x

    scale = (width/viewport_size) * shrink_factor
    scaled_points = list(map(lambda point: (0.0 if point[0] == 0.0 else (point[0]/scale), 0.0 if point[1] == 0.0 else (point[1]/scale)),points))
    return scaled_points
def findMaxX(points):
    xs = list(map(lambda point: point[0], points))
    return max(xs)
def findMinX(points):
    xs = list(map(lambda point: point[0], points))
    return min(xs)
```

Comment: Sometimes, even often, writing a "real" function with a name is much easier than trying to fit everything in a lambda with all its limitations...

Comment: A simple for loop to obtain scaled points might also be clearer than the map with lambda.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing `point[0]` and/or `point[1]` against 0.0 won't protect you from dividing by zero, because those are the numerator, not the denominator.

Try checking the denominator, `scale`, instead.

```
scaled_points = list(map(lambda point: (0.0 if scale == 0.0 else (point[0]/scale), 0.0 if scale == 0.0 else (point[1]/scale)),points))
```

Answer (score 0):

Also comparing floats, in whatever expression, requires care.  See the link https://stackoverflow.com/a/33024979/7312441

In your case it might help to add something like

```
scaled_points = list(map(lambda point: (0.0 if math.isclose(point[0], 0.0,rel_tol=1e-5) else (point[0]/scale), 0.0 if math.isclose(point[0], 0.0,rel_tol=1e-5)  else (point[1]/scale)),points))
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your lambda as follows:

> lambda point: (point[0]/scale if point[0] else 0.0,  point[1]/scale if point[1] else 0.0)